# Triple bubble conjecture: Natural candidate?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, surfaces

> Is there a standard natural candidate surface for
>   the shape that encloses three given volumes
>   in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and has minimal surface area?

I know the planar triple bubble conjecture was proved
by Wacharin Wichiramala in 2004 in a paper that I cannot access now
("Proof of the planar triple bubble conjecture." *Journal fur die Reine und Angewandte Mathematik* **567** (2004): 1-49).
I am guessing this paper may describe the candidate in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Perhaps "the" is already incorrect, in that there may be several candidate surfaces?
If so, the question could be narrowed to three equal volumes.

Ultimately I am seeking an image of the candidate(s), but any help here would be
appreciated—Thanks!

---

Thanks for everyone's help!
(I posted this summary at the same time j.c. was
providing his comprehensive answer.)
Here is an image made by [John Sullivan](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~jms/Images/obub.html):
"a standard cluster of three bubbles, where the surfaces are spherical. Any three desired volumes can be achieved by a Möbius transformation of this cluster":

 
 
 
 
[image: JohnSullivan3Bubbles]

And here is a photograph found at [this link](http://oumathclub.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/the-double-bubble-conjecture/):

 
 
 
 
[image: Photo3Bubbles]

(*Added 9Mar14*) j.c. found the original photo of the above and noticed it actually has
a tiny 4th bubble!

 
 
 
 
[image: 4th bubble]

Comment: You want Frank Morgan at Williams College. He and an undergraduate finished the double bubble conjecture. Which was about gum.  https://www.google.com/search?q=triple+bubble+conjecture&client=browser-ubuntu&hs=f4V&sa=G&channel=fe&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ei=YakaU5_5CNHdoASqg4G4BQ&ved=0CFsQsAQ&biw=1013&bih=741

Comment: There's a picture in this article: http://www.ugr.es/~aros/int.pdf .  The image is from John Sullivan at UIUC: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~jms/

Comment: See conjecture 2 for candidates with $3$ or $4$ bubbles: http://torus.math.uiuc.edu/jms/Papers/foams/soap-prob.pdf

Comment: Have you tried google image search? The first image that came up for me was a picture of the triple bubble, with the search "triple bubble conjecture".

Comment: Interestingly, the photo in your updated post actually seems to be of a non-standard 4 (or perhaps 5?) bubble.  See the original image from flickr: http://www.flickr.com/photos/sm/2603411754/sizes/o/ , labeled "triple bubble"

Comment: @j.c.: Sharp eyes and great sleuthing! The 4th bubble is clear. I added an enlargement from the link you provided.

Comment: Regarding [the paper mentioned in the question](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2038304) it seems that preprint is available [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Wacharin_Wichiramala/publication/243112132_Proof_of_the_planar_triple_bubble_conjecture/links/55dac43f08aec156b9ae836d.pdf). (However, I do not know to which extent the ResearchGate links can be considered reliable/permanent - I am not too familiar with that site.)

Comment: And there is also [thesis on the topic](http://www.math.sc.chula.ac.th/~wacharin/old/maths/thesisss.pdf) ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20180126000359/http://www.math.sc.chula.ac.th/~wacharin/old/maths/thesisss.pdf)) by the same author.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The triple bubble conjecture has [now been solved](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.09102) in dimensions at least 3.

Answer (score 12):

Problem 2 in [the list of open problems](http://torus.math.uiuc.edu/jms/Papers/foams/soap-prob.pdf) that Douglas Zare linked to answers the question (namely that **there is a standard candidate, and it is even called the standard triple bubble**).

I quote it here with a few interspersed comments of my own.

> **Problem 2** (Sullivan) We construct the standard clusters of k bubbles in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($k\leq n+1$) as follows. Start with a regular k-simplex in $S^{k-1}$, and lift this to $S^n$ along longitudes. Then consider different stereographic projections of this complex into Euclidean space; they have $S^{n-k}$ symmetry.

[The following is an image of the standard triple bubble in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as in Lucia's answer. It is by John Sullivan and it is on [this page of his website](http://torus.math.uiuc.edu/jms/Images/obub.html).]

[image: standard triple bubble]

> **Conj.** For any k prescribed volumes, there is a unique standard k-bubble with those volumes

[[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8101832/montesinosamilibia.pdf) is a copy of the paper by Montesinos proving existence (a result of Brakke's) and uniqueness of the standard clusters (Conj. 1). I am hosting a copy in my dropbox since it seems International Press has removed their online copy.]

> **Conj.** This standard k-bubble is uniquely area minimizing.

[As far as I know this is still open aside from the triple bubble case in the plane ([Wichiramala](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8101832/Wichiramala.pdf) (I'll host the paper for now)) and the double bubble case for $\mathbb{R}^n$ for all $n$ ([Reichhardt](http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.1601) and [another proof by Lawlor](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4580)).]

> **Conj.** For n=3, these are the only strictly stable k-bubbles ($k\leq 4$). Here we allow bubbles with disconnected regions; strictly stable means that the second variation is positive definite.

[[This paper of Morgan and Wichiramala](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2002-130-09/S0002-9939-02-06640-6/) proves that double bubbles (and two single bubbles) in 2D are the only stable bubbles with fixed area. See also [this paper of Cicalese, Leonardi and Maggi](http://cvgmt.sns.it/media/doc/paper/2017/CLM_2_preprint.pdf).]

> **Conj.** There is a strictly stable cluster of six bubbles with a non-spherical interface, but no such cluster has fewer bubbles.  ...

[I include an image from the same page of Sullivan's as above.].

[image: sullivan's six bubble cluster]

Comment: Regarding the last point in my answer (only tangentially-related to the question), Sullivan writes here http://archive.bridgesmathart.org/2014/bridges2014-453.html that he now believes there must be a stable nonspherical cluster of five bubbles, though he hasn't found one yet.